# Burned motor controllers: possible root causes analysis

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, component-failure, failure-analysis, failure-mode

On a submarine robot we built, during an operation, we recently had 3 defect thruster motors (the internal power PCBs have many burnt components, 2 of the motors cracked open due to internal pressure).

Short question: what might have caused it? Do you see any possibility other than inverting the power wires (my current hypothesis)?

**1) Quick description of the motors/controllers**

The motors are brushless DC motors. They integrate the control and power electronics in the form of 3 PCBs: one for the logic, one for the power stage, and a very small one for the Hall sensors. The logic PCB is supplied with +24 V DC (and supplies power to the Hall sensors), the power stage is powered by +320 V DC (and +24 V from the logic board, converted immediately to +15 V by an isolated converter on the power PCB).

The motors are designed to operate in salt water at a depth of several hundreds of meters. They are filled with insulating oil, and have a pressure compensation system (so generating a few cm³ of gas is not a problem).

**2) Analysis of the destroyed motors**

I spend the last 3 days analyzing the 3 motors in order to try to understand what happened.

**2.1) External aspects**

Motor 1: no destruction of mechanical parts.

Motor 2: it also “exploded”, but in a less spectacular way (only one of the metallic parts broke).

Motor 3: it literally “exploded”, breaking the 2 metallic parts holding it together (each maybe 15-20 mm² of section of aluminum).

On the inside :

motor 1: top side of power PCB:
[image: motor 1 (top)]

motor 1: bottom side of power PCB:
[image: motor 1 (bottom)]

motor 2: top side of power PCB:
[image: motor 2 (top)]

motor 2: bottom side of power PCB:
[image: motor 2 (bottom)]

motor 3: top side of power PCB:
[image: motor 3 (top)]

motor 3: bottom side of power PCB:
[image: motor 3 bottom]

As you can see, there is a big hole in the big DIP28 component, where more than 10mm³ burned: this probably generated enough gas to not only fill the available space in the pressure compensation system, but also to generate enough pressure to mechanically damage 2 of the 3 motors.

Note that only for motor 1 the (external) fuse burned, for the 2 other failures, the fuse was still intact after the motor burned. The fuses are supposed to be rated at 5 A.

**2.2) Motor checks**

I checked the motors themselves, to test if there are some shorts in the coils, or between a coil and the casing.

Motor 1: each coil has 12.1 Ω resistance. The case-to-coil resistance is >20 MΩ according to the multimeter, but only 20 kΩ @ 250 V with the insulation tester.

Motor 2: each coil has 12.0 Ω resistance. The case-to-coil resistance is more than 1 GΩ at 500 V (tested with insulation tester).

Motor 3: each coil has 11.8 Ω resistance. The case-to-coil resistance is more than 1 GΩ at 500 V (tested with insulation tester).

**2.3) detailed analysis of destroyed components of the power PCB**
The only PCB showing external signs of damage is the power PCB (containing mainly the 6 IGBTs (nb : an IGBT is an insulated gate bipolar transistor : it behaves roughly like a MOSFET), the IGBT driver (big component in the middle with the big burn hole), and the shunt resistor enabling to measure current.

I retro-engineered most of the PCB (I let aside some components that didn't seemed relevant, mainly capacitors):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feZ3SA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please note that all measures have be done in-circuit (for now I was instructed to do non-destructive tests only, if you see a destructive (or unsoldering) test that adds significant information, I can ask if I can perform it on one of the motors).

Below is the list of components I know are destroyed (on at least some PCBs). Non-listed components have not been tested (if one seems of interest to you, I’m happy to test it). For a more detailed list (detailed description per motor, datasheet links), see the attached  [Excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lggD4-zAOg_0v11SmQAkuUn2OlkjtJz1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114979101758137795961&rtpof=true&sd=true).

NB: after further investigations, the transistors are N-channel IGBTs, more precisely [IRG4BC30KD](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Infineon%20PDFs/IRG4BC30KDPbF.pdf) and not N-MOS as I initially wrote (the marking beeing on the bottom side, I just assumed they where MOSFETs as on the previous (low power) H bridges I worked with)

High side IGBTs (Q1, Q3 and Q5): gate and source are always shorted, for some, the drain is also shorted. On motor 3 only, the source pin of Q1 is totally burned (to the point of melting part of the pin), including part of the track starting from it (toward Q2’s drain and the connector too the coils). On motor 3 only, the track of the source pin of Q3 is also burned (under Q3, probably towards the shunt resistor).

Low side IGBTs (Q2, Q4 and Q6): gate and source are always shorted (excepted Q6 of motor 2), and sometimes the drain is also shorted.

1. IC1: the IGBT driver ([datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/5b1c/0900766b8138473f.pdf)): on all PCBs, there is a big burn hole in the middle (on motors 1 and 2 silicium is visible). On motor 3, there are several other burns on it: swollen just above the hole, and many burned pins:

- pin 1 (Vcc: +15 V) and maybe pin 2 (nHIN1: PWM input for the high-side IGBT Q1)
- pin 12 (VSS: power ground) and 13 (VS0: negative supply of the IGBTs, connected to ground by the shunt resistor), and maybe pin 11 (CA-: negative input of current amplifier)
- pin24 (VB2: bootstrap capacitor for high-side IGBT Q3), pin 25 (unused) and pin 26 (VS1: to gate of high-side IGBT Q1).

2 to 4): R10, R11, R12 (5.6 Ω nominal): connecting the Vsx pins of the driver to the source of high side IGBT, the drain of low-side IGBT and the motor coils: all destroyed (open circuit, excepted R12 for motor 3 which is now 10.4 kΩ). Visually, it goes from slightly burned to totally burned (nothing remains for R10 and R11 on motor 3, just a hole in the PCB).

5. R17 (0.1 Ω nominal, 2512 format (so probably rated between 1 and 3 W)): shunt resistor to measure current. State varies from one motor to another, but always destroyed:

- motor 1: strongly burned (the conductive metal strip is visible), measured 434 Ω
- motor 2: visually OK, measured >20 MΩ (i.e. open circuit)
- motor 3: visually OK, measured 194 Ω

I suspect the difference in failure modes of R17 explain that there are some differences in which other components where destroyed.

6 to 8) R7, R8, R9 (22 Ω nominal): gate resistors for the high-level IGBTs. All destroyed, but no or slight burn marks. For motors 1 and 2 they all failed open, for motor 3 they all failed to “high” resistance (150 Ω, 47 kΩ, 434 kΩ).

9 to 11) R13, R14, R15 (27 Ω nominal): all ended open circuit. Visually, only small burn marks are visible, except for R15 on motors 2 and 3 that look as if someone had properly unsoldered them!

12. R18 (10 kΩ nominal): part of the current measurement circuit:

- motor 1: visually OK, measured 2.09 kΩ in-circuit
- motor 2: unsoldered, open circuit
- motor 3: burned, measured 1.93 kΩ in-circuit

13. R19 (2.2 kΩ nominal) : part of the current measurement circuit:

- motor 1: visually OK, measured 1.81 kΩ in circuit
- motor 2: burned, measured 80 kΩ in circuit
- motor 3: visually OK, measured 1.00 k&ihm; in circuit

14. IC5: isolation amplifier ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/678/AV02_1289EN_2021_05_24-1828261.pdf)): motor 1: visually OK, no shorts. Motors 2 and 3: cracked (but no burn marks).
15. PCB track between the source of low-side IGBT Q6 and the VS0 pin of the IGBT driver (i.e. pseudo ground after shunt resistor). Motor 1: all OK (both visually and resistance measured at 0.4 Ω). Motors 2 and 3: copper visible (but no burn marks), open circuit.

16 to 18) IC2, IC3, IC4 ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/678/AV01-0546EN_2019-08-06-1828017.pdf)): 2-channel optocouplers between command signals and IGBT driver inputs. On motor 3 only: shorts between VCC and GND pins (no burn marks). On other motors, no shorts, visually OK

**2.4) Operational considerations**
Please note that those are indirect records, and that they were compiled well after the fact. So don’t rely too much on this part, and don’t hesitate to propose explanations that don’t match this succession of events.

1. There is a reversal between power ground and +320 V supply of the whole ROV (due to bad wiring of the tether on the ship). The first power stage and some fuses and converters where destroyed. After replacement by spares, everything seemed to work fine (but there might have been some “hidden” damage). Note that no motor seemed to be destroyed, and that only one of the motors later destroyed (motor 1) was connected at that point (the 2 other should have been spares).
2. Motor 1 was the one originally mounted, and failed at the beginning of a dive (supposedly a pre-dive check is performed, checking in-air that all motors turn, but it might have been skipped for whatever reason). The (external) 5 A fuse burned.
3. The broken motor (1) is replaced by a spare (motor 2), at the same location. As far as I understood, it turned for some time (a few seconds or several dives, it’s unclear), but don’t rely on it. Supposedly at the beginning of a dive, it also failed, without burning the new fuse (normally same ratings).
4. As far as I understood, a motor from another part (motor 4) of the robot was mounted at the location where 2 motors had already burned, and a new spare (motor 3) was mounted where motor 4 was before. After a time unknown to me, motor 3 also was destroyed (it’s the only one that “exploded” strong enough to spill the oil it contained).

So to summarize, what I know for sure, is that there was an inversion of power ground and +320 V DC at the beginning, but that not all 3 motors where connected at that point (probably only motor 1). All the rest is not very reliable, and should be viewed as clues but not as certain facts.

**2.5) Side note on low voltage supply**

The low voltage supply (+24 V DC) comes from the control board (which suffered no visible harm), and is converted to +15 V DC through an isolated DC/DC converter ([datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/be3b/0900766b81690260.pdf)). The grounds of the converter are not connected. The ground for the +15 V side is connected to directly to the power ground.

**3) Interpretation**

So far, the only way I found to explain the observed damage is the inversion between +320 V and ground on the motors (due to a wiring problem for example). There are so many components burned that clearly the current didn’t do a single current loop, but many, which seems an argument against a short circuit somewhere.

A polarity inversion, on the contrary, seems to explain it rather well: most/all MOSFET/IGBT- based components behave like a diode when in reverse polarity. So there are many low resistivity paths that become available, and they will burn one after another until no low resistivity path remains.

There are many low resistivity paths (for reverse polarity), that burned on all (or nearly all) motors:

- diodes D4 to D6 followed by resistors R11 to R13 followed by high-side IGBTs Q1, Q3, Q5 behaving like diodes
- shunt resistor R17 (0.1 Ω) followed by a IGBT pair (Q2+Q1, Q4+Q3, Q6+Q5) that behaves like 2 diodes in series.
- probably many paths through the IGBT driver (having the +320 V on VSS and nearly +320 V on VS0 pin), followed by the gate resistors and the IGBTs
- once the shunt resistor R17 had burned, the current might have passed through R19 and R18 instead: it isn’t a low resistivity path (2.2 kΩ + 10 kΩ), but at 320 V, it is still 30 mA, which makes a total of 10.6 W dissipated between the 2 resistors (more than enough to burn them too).

The only part for which I’m quite unsure, is how the 3 optocouplers (IC2, 3, 4) on motor 3 and the isolated amplifier (IC5) on motors 2 and 3 also got damaged. I would guess that the Vcc input of the IGBT driver (IC1) got somehow shorted to something else (which would explain the burn marks on the Vcc pin of the driver on motor 3).

**Do you confirm that a polarity inversion between power-GND and +320 V can explain the observed damage?**

**Do you see any other cause that might give the observed symptoms?**

**As *Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica* suggested, there is the option of high-voltage transients. But can they be powerful enough to generate such damage (there was enough energy dissipated to make one motor "explode", to melt some metal pins, to burn through a 12.2 kΩ path, ...)?

EDIT: to answer the questions from comments:

- we are manufacturing the ROV (so I have access to full schematics), but the motor is bought "off the shelve" (just replacing the cable going to the ROV)
- +320 V DC is produced on the ship (from 3 x 230 V AC) with a power supply also measuring "earth" leakage (to ship hull I suppose)
- +24 V DC is generated on the ROV from the +320 V (and supplied to the power PCB through the command PCB (both being inside the motor))
- the supply for each individual motor is fused in the ROV : 5 A for +320 V and 3 A for +24 V
- as far as I know, no leakage detection is measured between +320 V and +24 V
- as far as I know, no high-voltage transient protections (except capacitors and inductance for +24 V, capacitors only for +320 V, but they don't add much protection). Good point to add them to the next version. Do you think high-voltage transients might explain the damage we observed?
- I agree with Kuba that probably the error is outside the ROV (human error (ex: inverting 2 wires), external cause, design error, ...)

EDIT 2 :

- I did a mistake : we did not operate the motors at 360V as I initially wrote, but at 320V (which is the nominal for the motor, 360V being the maximum). I remembered that at some point we increased to 360V (a few month before operations, when we had a converter not working properly because of too much resistance loss in tether), but I had missed the fact that we went back to 320V once problem was solved by using another converter. I edited in the initial post, but I can't edit the comments.
- the "MOSFETs" turned out to be N-channel IGBTs instead : [IRG4BC30KD](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Infineon%20PDFs/IRG4BC30KDPbF.pdf). Voltage rating is 600V.
- the diodes ([STTH212U](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/389/stth212-1852067.pdf)) are rated 1200V, and the IGBT-driver ([R2130PBF](https://docs.rs-online.com/5b1c/0900766b8138473f.pdf)) is rated 600V. So in the circuit, if I'm not mistaken, everything (excepted maybe the capacitor C27) should be able to withstand a spike up to 600V if it is short enough (in order to avoid thermal issues due to increased current).
- as already mentioned in comments, I did some simulations based on the inductance of the tether, and the inductance of the motor : neither is causing voltage spikes (the damping factor is >=5, so we are strongly over-damped and don't risk oscillations causing spikes)

Comment: Each motor supply must be individually fused - both 24V and high voltage. What are the fuse values you’re using right now for this purpose? How are you generating the 360V supply on the ship? How do you test the integrity of the tether cable? Cables for ROVs require a continuous leakage detection circuit - both between high voltage and low voltage wiring, but also between high voltage and water (ship frame).

Comment: The motors you use have no protection against high voltage transients, and also seemingly none at the 24V input. Are they something you buy, or your own designs? Parts that go into *cars* are more robust.

Comment: For the high voltage (+360V), each motor has its own 5A fuse (NB : no way to check if it is really the case, the robot is stored in the country of operation, at the opposite side of the world : we just received the damaged motors back for analysis).
For the +24V (coming via the command PCB), I will don't know the fuse ratings, I will check

Comment: Also, all external HV wiring on the ROV requires continuous electrical leakage detection just like for the tether. So, each motor cable must be monitored for leakage from HV to water and from HV to low voltage circuits.

Comment: Are you the manufacturer of the motors or of the ROV? The design of the entire system is of utmost importance. You’ll learn nothing much just looking at the motors. The motors have not “failed” most likely. They were destroyed by problems elsewhere. Without having full documentation for the entire vehicle and doing a thorough review, you’ll be probably just wasting your time.

Comment: We are manufacturing the ROV, but buying the motors "of the shelve" (just changing the cable going to the ROV).
The +360V is generated on the ship with a power supply taking 3 phase "mains" (230V per phase). The power supply integrates "earth" leakage (I suppose to the ship frame).

Comment: I agree that the root cause is probably outside the motors (bad wiring, bad manipulation, conception error in the ROV, ...), but I was hopping to identify how the motor were destroyed (polarity inversion, high voltage transients, ...) in order to guess the real problem (ideally it would just be human error, but it might also be some design error making that it might occur again)

Comment: Is the design yours? What’s the length of the tether? Have you simulated the inductance of the cable and the voltage transient caused by it when you go from max thrust to off? In the last underwater drone project I was involved with this effect was substantial but probably longer tether and more power than I see here. If the design is yours, how come you use through hole in 2022? Also, TO-220 may be the cheapest but your mechanically worst option.

Comment: The design of the PCBs inside the motors is not ours (they are integrated in the motors we buy "of the shelve"). I know we did some testing on the resistivity of the tethers, but I'm not sure we did some study of the inductance. I will ask about it (and about the precise length and inductance of the tether we used on this operation)

Comment: Please do. I’m inclined to call the design bad, or at least unsuitable for an RV. Do you have room in your vehicle to have PCB in front of the motor driver?

Comment: It seems tno studies were performed on the inductance of the tether (it is not specified by the datasheet). Resistivity is given as ≤ 26.70 ohm/km @ 20°C for 1 0.75mm² conductor. We use 4 such conductors (2 for ground, 2 for return) : the 2 with same signal are just separated by insulation, the distance between ground and +360V wires is about 7.5mm. So (supposing one 1.5mm² wire per voltage) I get a total induction of 0.35 mH. Total current of the ROV is <20A. So for 10V overshoot, I would need : dt=L*di/dv=3.5*10^-4 * 20 / 10=7*10^-4 s. I will check if we apply any pwm ramp to stop motors

Comment: I checked, there is no deceleration ramp in software. I don't know if there is one implemented in the micro-controller embedded in the motors

Comment: 0.35 mH isn’t too bad at 20 A. Set up that in your favorite simulator along with cable R and any filter capacitors on the board and simulate a rapid shut off. What’s the voltage rating on the MOSFETs and capacitor? Do you do any cable R compensation at the ship to compensate for cable losses?

Comment: You mention the power was reversed at some point. Do you have any sort of reverse-power protection on the circuit? Wouldn't be a bad idea to either add that or change the connectors used to make it impossible to plug in backwards in the future, even if that wasn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: One thing that stands out to me is that the MOSFET leads are soldered to pads that are spaced at 0.1", so that the space between pads will probably be very small, on the order of 20 mils. IPC-2221B track spacing rules specify minimum 16 mils for 300 V peak and 32 mils for 500 V peak. https://www.smpspowersupply.com/ipc2221pcbclearance.html. The leads of the TO-220 packages should be spread out to 0.2" spacing on the PC board.

Comment: To me this looks like the 3 motors were killed until someone finally noticed the reverse polarity error. First the shunt resistor dies and then the chip explodes.

Comment: @winny :I will do the simulations on Monday, and look into the mosfet max voltage (and the one for the capacitor if I can find it). Compensation for cable resistivity is not done yet (it's currently studied).

Comment: @Hearth : the connectors are all in such way that it is impossible to connect them the wrong way. But on the operation a new tether was used, and it was I'll connect. But adding some reverse polarity protection is definitively a good idea.

Comment: @PStechPaul : what do you imply? That the insulation might have broken down due to too small track spacing?

Comment: @Jens : it is indeed possible that 3 motor were destroyed before the reverse polarity was noticed, but I would like te see if there is any other possibility than such a gross error.

Comment: If track or pad spacing is too small, it is possible that the solder mask coating could break down, or there could be solder flux residue or "tin whiskers" from the solder that could provide sharp pointed conductors that could arc at 350 volts, especially if higher voltage transients occur. Perhaps a conformal coating after soldering could reinforce the insulation, but best practice is to spread the leads to provide sufficient spacing.

Comment: @PStechPaul : this I undestand, but we do not design/manufacture the motors (including command and power PCBs) ourself, we buy them of the shelve. So do you suggest that the "small" spacing might cause arcs that destroyed the PCBs as described? Or that this small spacing should be a red flag telling us not to buy these motors?

Comment: @winny : sorry, I somehow missed your message about adding a PCB in front of the motor driver. What do you have in mind? It should be possible to somehow squeeze a small PCB in the pod (ie between the 360 + 24 V and the motors). If something bigger is required, if for testing, we might remove another PCB from the pod, or add a small extra pod for it. If for permanent usage, we will probably need either to adapt one of the PCBs or manufacture a bigger pod)

Comment: If you can find another source for these components, it might be good to buy a couple and inspect the boards to see if spacing is better on the high voltage tracks and pads. You might also buy more of the ones that failed, to verify the spacing. It may help if you cut away some of the MOSFET pads to increase spacing, and then use a good conformal coating to reinforce the insulation. Have you contacted the vendor to report this issue and maybe request a design modification?

Comment: @winny : I did the simulations with tether resistance and inductance today : there is no overshooting. I also did the computation based on the equivalent RLC circuit : I got an damping factor of 5 (ie strong overdamping), so the voltage at the motors is not oscillating and there is no overshooting.

Comment: Very good! Then probably no need for a front-end filter PCB but also you are back to square one. What’s the voltage rating for the motor with integrated driver and what MOSFETs did they use?

Comment: The motor is rated 320V nominal and 360V max (nb : I was mistaken : we supply it with 320V, the 360V was only at some point in the workshop but was reverted to 320V). And the transistors are N-channel IGBTs : https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Infineon%20PDFs/IRG4BC30KDPbF.pdf . Both IGBTs and driver-IC are rated 600V as absolute max (the diodes even 1200V). I corrected my initial post and added an edit to clarify those points

Comment: This kind of effect always makes me think of an issue with the freewheeling diodes first.  Supposing that motor A's normal current flow is suddenly interrupted, how can the coil get rid of its energy?  The diodes directly connected to it do not allow a closed loop current - they are mounted opposite to each other.  When a coil can not get rid of its energy, it will increase its voltage until it can and this can break your chip.

Comment: @le_top : Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please explain a bit more in detail? Do you mean that the freewheeling diodes just send current back to the main supply, making the voltage rise (and that we might not have enough capacitance on the main supply to absorb this current with reasonable voltage increase)? But if so, how do you explain that there are so many different paths that fail, and not just one (once the current can pass somewhere, it should be enough to get rid of energy). Whats more, I would be surprised that the inertia of a thruster is enough to energy to make it explode

Comment: For my part, I would guess transient overvoltage or reversal.  Most likely, adequate fusing and a nice TVS (400V worth, may need two 200V in series) at the module would address this, if it is indeed the cause of course.  To clarify, these are purchased modules, not internal designs? If you're asking about potential circuit changes, I can think of a few, but there are other (procedural/management) issues at play if that is the case.

Comment: I see that there are commutating diodes for the lower IGBTs, but not the upper devices. I know these IGBTs have integral high-speed diodes, but as the high side devices seem to be sustaining damage, maybe they are inadequate. Also perhaps more bus capacitance is needed, especially close to the drivers. There none shown on the schematic, but you say that you did not include them. However, they would be rather large - perhaps several hundred uF and 600V+ rated.

Comment: It WOULD help if you included images of the motors, one of the good one, and maybe 2 pictures of each of the destroyed motors, with a view from the inside and an external view of at least one side.

Comment: I'm not sure to get what exactly you want : images from the motors itselfs? (ie the mecanical part? the stator?) I can take some more pictures start of January, once I'm back in office if needed. But what information do you think you might get from it? Also, we managed to repair one of the motors by replacing the burned power PCB. So it seems that there was (at least on that one) no problem neither with the stator, the hall sensors, nor the control PCB.

Comment: There is a trace on the "transistor/bottom side" of the motor 2 power PCB standing out for its coppery colour. A damage to the same trace is visible with motor 3. Would it be possible that du/dt from the power side gets the better of components on the other side? While `insulating oil` isn't glycerol, it does increase parasitic capacities.

Comment: @Sandro - It looks like the problem was here: "logic PCB is supplied with +24V" - The voltage was to high (320V) or inverted (-24V or -320V). Is the IL2415S working? After the driver chip was destroyed the gate of the IGBTs are loades with a random voltage. So you got a high steady current flow over a random motor-coil. If the 320V would be inverted, then the current would simply go over the Body-Diodes of the IGBTs and the little 0.1 Ohm R17 would be always the fuse. Sad that there is no protection against incorrect operation. Diodes in the +24V and +320V powerline would have saved the day.

Comment: @MicroPower : it's an interesting guess, that might have been a valid explanation, excepted that since I posted this topic (and all discussions ended), we ordered new power PCBs, and tried to use them with the existing logic PCBs, and everything worked OK. If 320V DC, -24V or -320V had been supplied to the logic PCB, I suppose it would have been destroyed as well.

Answer (score 2):

I played with motors in an underwater craft before - very good write up on your issues.

I would try this exactly:

setup a system and add instrumentation (scope), perhaps thermal camera and take a look at what goes on with the following conditions:

- normal motor load (in water)
- stalled motor
- water with debris (use the motor to drive a DC motor 1:1 with a variable load, or equivalent)
- does something special happen when the battery is further along discharge ?

Inspect waveforms and thermals on all those conditions.

Usually underwater things fail due to some leakage of salt water but this does not appear to be your case, but I would check for chloride salts also with an XCF type device on your boards, or outsource that analysis.

Usually you don't see chip packages getting destroyed on low voltage normal power situations, so I do suspect you are getting a big spike somehow.

It's possible something much larger is coming in on your 320 line every once in a while. Might be good to monitor that also with a scope of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

@sandro This is to clarify my comment as you requested:

[image: Current flow when drive is interrupted]

Suppose that the current in coil A is running in the shown direction (blue downward arrow).

Then, suppose that the motor drive is suddenly interrupted by the IC/IGBTs.

At that point, the current going in the coil has to continue flowing as it can not decrease in 0 time.

Without the diode shown it seems that the current might continue to flow though the IC and GND as shown - or some other path.  So the energy could have to be absorbed by the IC.
The coil will rise to whatever voltage needed to keep the same current flowing (at the moment the external drive stops).

When adding the diode in magenta ("free running diode", the current would flow through that diode and coil A gets rid of its energy at a low voltage level.

Can this break your IC to the point it explodes?
It depends on how much energy your coil(s) have to release.
The process might be repeating under some conditions, heat up the IC more and more and then have a final fatal injection of energy.

A friend once reported he had a design where there were a lot of customer returns with burnt components.  I had a look and suggested him to add a freerunning diode.  About a year later we talked about it again and he told me the issue was gone with that.

My guess is that D4-D6 are intended to be the freerunning diodes, but I'ld expect them to be across the coils, not to GND.

Do note that I did not make a detailed analysis of your schematic or how the IC and drivers work here.  There is no guarantee that this is the issue, I am just suggesting to carefully check how the current can safely flow when your driver is no longer driving the motor.

Even if you under normal conditions the IC would manage the motor correctly (interrupt the driver only at a zero current crossing for instance), you might have unexpected power interruptions for instance that prevent the IC from doing the work.

Edit:
The above is not (exactly) applicable, but the application note [AN985](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Six-Output_600V_MGDs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f95501236)
shows diodes to V+Power.  Check if that is needed:
[image: Figure 9 from the application note]

Comment: The IGBTs contain co-pack diodes; these diodes are redundant, and there are positive diodes sinking this flow to +V. Presumably there is a bypass capacitor there (the uncoated stacked film part?), not shown on the schematic.

Comment: You can't use diodes across the BLDC motor coils, because they are driven with AC, much like a VFD for an induction motor. But there should be matching diodes to the DC bus link, to form a three phase rectifier to carry generated current.

Comment: @PstechPaul I throw in the application note that confirms that the diodes are not to be mounted accross the motor coils and that probably has other interesting stuff to learn from it https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Six-Output_600V_MGDs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f95501236

Comment: Thanks for the details. Indeed, if current couldn't go back the +320V, voltage would rise until the current could break through the driver IC. I don't think the supply itself can accept current back, however, there are several capacitors that should be able to accept the current : the uncoated staked part mentioned by @TimWilliams is indeed a capacitor, and there are several other capacitors on other circuits connected on the same +320V bus (outside the PCB). Do you know how exactly to double check if there is enough capacitance?

Comment: For the "figure 9", I don't think it's the most relevant, as the motor phases are connected between VS and a transistor leeding to GND, istead of beeing connected between 2 VS pins. Figure 7 of the same document https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Six-Output_600V_MGDs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf fits better the real circuit.

Comment: To double check if there is enough capacitance, as a first approche I would use the maximum current flowing in the coils, estimate the energy that represents, and check how much voltage rise there would be in the capacitor to absorb that energy.  Then consider if that is reasonable or not.  If not reasonable, this does not mean it is bad, but if it is reasonable you can stop there.